# Changing linum-mode face background uniformly

Tags: faces, themes

I've been trying to change my line numbers background to be a different colour other than the background colour of my frames and it ended up looking like so :-

[image]

How can I change the line numbers background colour to be uniform throughout and not only till the last line of the buffer?

Comment: This is not possible, sorry.  The best you can achieve is a fringe that goes from top to bottom, but the line numbers will appear to the left of the fringe, and the line numbers will still stop colorization at the last line of the buffer.

Comment: Thats a bummer. I'll just delete this question since it has no solution or should I keep it as is ?

Comment: Sometimes the "answer" is that this feature is not presently available.  Perhaps someone else might have an interesting alternative such as the fringe (which can be colorized), and there is an optional colorization for the fringe when it is beyond the end of the buffer -- e.g., the fringe from window-start to the end of the buffer can be one color, and a different color (in the form of bitmap images) can be used from the end of the buffer to the bottom of the window.  Maybe someone else will offer another angle that I have not thought of, so go ahead and leave it open for now.

Comment: I would like to change the background too. What and where need to be changed? By the way: it should be possible to patch the linum-mode elisp code to achieve the effect you want adding also a toggle allowing to switch back to the old behavior. Have you tried to check the code to find out how to do it?